# Clearing out 'Choose a locator:' drop-down

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, find, geocoding-service

We are using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 with concurrent licensing. One of the basic tools within ArcGIS Desktop is Find (Binocular icon).  Within this tool, I can search for an address using either the World Geocoding Service or my own locator.

How can I clear the drop-down of all the old locators that we do not have or use anymore?

Basically we are looking for a clean slate without resorting to an uninstall/reinstall methodology.

[image: Find Tool]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where this information is stored but customisation is stored in the normal.mxt template. Often when ArcMap plays up then deleting this template does a "factory reset". On the next start up of ArcMap the normal.mxt is recreated.

**WARNING**: This deletes ALL customisation, so any toolbars or addins you have added and any corporate customisation of the interface is lost. So you have to be 100% sure you want to remove this file, normally people rename it and if the removal of the template did not fix the problem then people can reinstate the template.

On my computer, which is running ArcMap 10.6 the template is here:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcMap\Templates
```

xxxx = is your profile name

I can't promise this will work as maybe the locator information is stored elsewhere? Having just written this I noticed that there is a folder called:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\Locators
```

May be that is where this information is stored?

Comment: Thanks, Hornbydd.  I went ahead and deleted the Normal.mxt file and it DID reset my toolbars to the default.  No worries there. However, it kept the locator drop-down intact. I also checked the Locators folder and there was nothing of value there either.  I'll continue my search, but you did give me other avenues to look at.